# Uncaught TypeError with undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I get error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

With the following JavaScript code:

```
var varId = $("#someInputId");
if (typeof varId !== "undefined" && varId.val().length == 0)
```

Where `varId` is the id of an input element that may be or may not be in the HTML page.

I suppose that if element is undefined the second clause does not computed.

Any ideas why I get such error?

Comment: `underfined` ? Did you mean `undefined`?

Comment: varId.length  not varId.val().length

Comment: Is this the new NFL app Roger Goodell developed, where it determines whether you've received enough fines or have been "underfined"?

Comment: fix "undefined" misprint

Comment: Is this jQuery, and if so, what version? If there is no jQuery, what is `val()` and what is `$`

Comment: It sounds like that jQuery either cannot find the element or it is not a form control element (assuming you are using jQuery at all).

Comment: @Cherry You were misleading us, `varId` always exists, since looks like it's a jQuery object now.

Comment: @FelixKling wow that's true jQuery does return `undefined` instead of the empty string when there is no elements :o The documented return values are string, number, array

Comment: @Teemu `$().val()` returns `undefined`. `null` for option elements when no option is selected as well. Could it be more messier

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the jQuery object is probably empty.

Let's just go through your code step by step:

```
var varId = $("#someInputId");
```

So after this, you have a jQuery object referenced by varId. Keep in mind, this is a jQuery **object**, regardless of the number of elements that were returned. Now you do this:

```
if (typeof varId !== "undefined" && varId.val().length == 0)
```

<s>First thing here, and not sure if this was just a typo in the question, !== should be !=.</s>

Anyway, consider the `typeof varId != "undefined"` part of the condition. This will return true, since varId is an object and is not undefined. Since this is true, the condition evaluation moves on to the next part. So while evaluating `varId.val().length == 0`, you're getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. In order for something to have the length property, it must be a string or an array, and `val()` in jQuery returns a string, or an array in the case of a multiple select input. However, if the jQuery object is empty, then val() will return `undefined`, which doesn't have a length property.

So basically, you can rewrite the expression as follows:

```
if ( varId.length && varId.val().length === 0 ) {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: The following is not true:  `!==` should be `!=`. In fact, one should always be in the habit of using `===` and `!==` unless one has a *very good reason* not to test complete equality.

Comment: Noted, removing that from the answer.

Comment: `varId.length` is still defined, even if the query returned no objects, so your test wouldn't work.

Comment: Actually, it was my understanding that if the value of `varId.length` is 0, it's evaulated as false anyway. So there's no need for tests like `varId.length === 0` or `varId.length > 0`

Comment: @DerekHenderson Just read the question again and realised the second part of my condition was wrong anyway! Edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to take the length of `undefined` (i.e., `undefined.length`), which is what is throwing the 'Uncaught TypeError' error.

Clearly, `$("#someInputId")` is undefined or returns no results.  Most likely, `$("#someInputId")` returned no results, and the value of an empty set is undefined.

Your conditional check reaches the second clause because `$()` will always instantiate a jQuery object. But if the jQuery object is empty, its value will be undefined.

To avoid this error, you need to check that your query returns a result:

```
var varId = $("#someInputId");
if (varId.length > 0 && varId.val().length === 0) {
```

That conditional will be true if `#someInputId` exists and has a value of 0.

Comment: Uh? `$()` returns a jQuery object, so `varId` *is* a jQuery object.

Comment: @FelixKling, the OP edited her question several minutes after it was posted.  My edits reflect her edits -- you just happened to join the conversation mid-stream!  ;)

Comment: Ah I see that now. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

> Where varId is id of input element that may be or not in the ntml page.

If the can be that the element does not exist, then you have to check whether the jQuery object contains any elements:

```
if (varId.length && ...) {
```

`$` will *always* return a jQuery object, even if it didn't select any elements (and thus will never be `undefined`). But calling `.val` on an empty selection will return `undefined`.

Also make sure that you are executing the code after the DOM is ready. Please read the [jQuery tutorial "How jQuery Works"](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/) to learn how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   if ($("#someInputId").val()!= undefined &&
           $("#someInputId").val().length == 0)
```

Answer (score -1):

There is onlu in jQuery a `val()` function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<input id="varId" value="varIdValue" />
<p id="output"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var varId = $("#varId");
  var output = $("#output");
  output.html((typeof varId == "undefined") + ' ' + varId.val() + ' ' + varId.val().length);
</script>
```

Output will be: `false varIdValue 10`

If you not use jQuery, then you must use `value` property like this:

```
var varId = document.getElementById('varId');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
output.innerHTML = (typeof varId == "undefined") + ' ' + varId.value + ' ' + varId.value.length;
```

And output wil be the same: `false varIdValue 10`

**EDIT**

```
var varId = document.getElementById('doesntExist');
var varIdIsObject = (typeof varId == "object");
```

`varId` will be `null` and `varIdIsObject` will be true

But in jQuery:

```
var varId = $('#doesntExist');
```

`varId` will be jQuery Object with 2 fields: `context` (HTMLDocument) and `selector` (in our variant is '#doesntExist').